# Mouse cursor sticking / dissapearing, regardless of OS

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, mouse

I bought a computer a year and a half ago (it was a custom PC) with Windows 7. 6 months later I upgraded to Windows 8. Everything was fine until a month ago, when my cursor started to stick to the screen (can't move it for between 10 seconds and a minute).

It stayed like that for a month, but yesterday my mouse pointer completely disappeared. So I thought it might be a Window 8 problem so I formatted my PC and downgraded to Windows 7, but the cursor still displays the same problems as before.

Do you think it might be an hardware problem and if yes which pieces?

I tried 3 different mice and I have changed their batteries.

/// EDIT

I tried different USB port, for updating my graphic (nvidia geforce 210 series). In manage computer it said that the driver is up to date. The problem starts without having update any driver or install new component or application.

Comment: probably a driver problem, try updating your graphics card drivers.

Comment: If you have this problem in a clean install, then the remaining problems are either driver-related (as @Colin stated, upgrade the graphics driver) or hardware-related (maybe a damaged USB port). Can you provide more information about your setup?

Comment: Are there any other problems worth mentioning? Do the cursor disappearances occur in any noticeable pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem (sorry I'm late posting this), the probleme was as stupid as this.... inteference with my wi-fi !

I noticed that on the other end of my desk, the mouse was perfectly fine ! So after few test I found that the nearest of my d-link I was bigger problem I have !

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of Sensitivity of mouse or a driver problem

Try lowering down the sensitivity by going in the touch pad options

Update the drivers for touchpad/mouse